# Project Management WebApp Ideas?

Tags: web-applications, project-management

My company is currently developing a project management web application in PHP, and I am looking for some ideas for interesting and popular features that we could include.

The things we plan to include are:

- Sharing of tasks and tracking of milestones
- Time management - tracking who put how much time into what task
- File uploads and sharing
- A sort of wiki or commonly editable page

Some more ideas would be very much appreciated,
Thanks, RayQuang

Comment: Is this an internal app or something you hope to sell? If it's internal remember than anything *you* build, *you* will have to support. I'd encourage looking at the rest of the open source world first. If you're hoping to sell it, good luck. There are *hundreds* of free/paid alternatives. Unless you have a particular niche, you're fighting a lot of established competition. I'm the project lead for web2project (LAMP-based, Open Source) and it's *hard* building a community, even when some are willing to drop in cash.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get more ideas from existing project management web apps:

- [Basecamp](http://basecamphq.com/tour/)
- [Redmine](http://www.redmine.org/wiki/redmine/Features)
- [Activecollab](http://www.activecollab.com/#tour)

Answer (score 1):

I recommend [JIRA](http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/) & [Confluence Wiki](http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/) (of Atlassian). Another good-enough tool is [Trac](http://trac.edgewall.org/),it is not easy to configure but it's free.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at podio.com they allow you to build your own apps and relate data between them.

Also pay a great deal attention to power users. Keyboard short cuts etc.

Have a look at Licorize.com as well. It's like Gtd of bookmarking but also usable for project management.

Lastly Kanban seems to be hot in web apps right now.